# Android library problems

Tags: android

I am looking to use the android sample project 'Bluetooth chat' as a library so that I can use it inside another application.

I have marked the project as a library in its properties and I have referenced the project in my application. I understand I need to update my applications manifest file, however I am totally lost as to what needs to be added/changed(I am a total beginner).

I am just looking to launch the sample from the click of a button within my application.

I have read [the documentation about referencing](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) but I am still pretty confused. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you be more specific on your doubt? Please download these two projects https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator it contains a library project and a sample application.

Comment: What actually do you want to achieve? Do you just want to learn android Bluetooth

Comment: I am looking to open the bluetooth chat sample from within my application on the click of a button.

Comment: Adding a project as a library will allow you to use some of it's functionality, but that doesn't mean it will tell you HOW to use it. If a project isn't meant to be a library it is unlikely that you will be able to get it to do what you want it to do, it might not even be documented and might have thousands of lines of code to read through to decipher how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

if you access your project you enter your manifest file for entry lie that

```
 <activity
  android:name="<Package name>.<java file name>"
    />
```

Make Sure your lib and your project in same folder.